# Why didn't the FBI trace the getaway truck?

Tags: plot-explanation, going-in-style

Maybe there was a scene that I missed in *Going in Style* (2017), but I thought the first thing the FBI would do is tracing the getaway truck.

Sure they are wearing masks but in my opinion using a truck from the festival as a getaway car was stupid since it could be traced back to them. But it's odd the FBI don't even ask about it.

So, Why didn't the FBI trace the getaway truck?

Comment: I am pretty sure it was a random bus that they hijacked. The latino guy taught them how to

Answer (score 1):

We don't know that they didn't, **but**...

The getaway BUS was deliberately chosed NOT to look like a typical getaway car. It's referenced in the movie that the getaway vehicle was chosen to look as though it belonged there and wouldn't be obvious.

Then we don't know that anyone saw the van/bus leave the bank so it may not have been known that it WAS the getaway vehicle.

Additionally, without a licence plate the van/bus looks just like **every other bus** and is parked with other buses *looking exactly the same*.

[image]

Tracing the vehicle **takes time** and, even if they could, they already had the guys arrested in the space of 24-48 hours.

In short, they might have traced it...but they didn't need to.